# Can't use elasticsearch in local Docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, windows-10

I've just moved from docker toolbox to windows 10 with docker (Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea).
I need to use elasticsearch with my java application, but i can't work with it - the port 9300 seems to be unaccessable. My actions:
I've pulled a elasticsearch image from dockerhub

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1
```

and run it with a bridge network, exposing ES posts: 9200, 9300

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "ES_HOST=0.0.0.0"
```

container works, and bot ports are available on localhost (i guess so), because whe i curl then from command line i get:

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -i -s -X GET http://localhost:9200
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 425

{
  "name" : "hAdBv7c",
  "cluster_name" : "mycluster",
  ...
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and the node communication port:

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -i -s -X GET http://localhost:9300
This is not a HTTP port
```

So, this convinces me that everything works fine... But i cannot get any elasticsearch data...
I had all this working at docker toolbox, but with a little difference in parameter: ES_HOST=192.168.99.100

It seems that docker toolbox worked differently and had a default ip address for decker machine. So i had only to forward ES to an appropriate address. 
Here at windows 10 docker something wents wrong when passing data by 9300 port but now i can't map ES to docker ip directly.
I've tried to bind it to host network, but this makes no sense: http://localhost:9200 or http://localhost:9300 is unavailable...

Any ideas?

Comment: If curl can talk to localhost on 9200 and 9300, elasticsearch and docker are probably working just fine. Where is your java code? As a side note when you are developing on your local machine you should set ES_HOST to `127.0.0.1`. It is possible that other machines on your network could poke your ES node at the moment.

Comment: Yes, i've tried to use 127.0.0.1 as ES_HOST, but i assume this binds only a loopback interface as an only possible at ES container... so it doesn't work...

Comment: Silly question, but, I can't find any documentation anywhere referencing a `ES_HOST` environment variable.  How do you know this works?

Comment: That's a good question, in short this is an environment variable that defines the value of network.host parameter. I was able to find it only manually and I've missed it in the topic description... Maybe it doesn't affect at all :)